# Use userfaultfd to keep track of accesses to memory

Tags: c, memory-management, linux-kernel

I am looking for methods which would allow me to keep track of user space accesses to virtual memory. My basic 2 requirements are

1. To be able to tell whether an access is a read or a write.
2. To be able to do that repeatedly, i.e. these were the accesses for that period of time, reset the protection/tracking mechanism and track all accesses again.

For the moment I am using the `PROT_NONE+SIGSEGV` trick. When there's an access there's a segmentation fault signal generated which I catch and handle. The handler will tell if it's a write or read and remove the protection. When the time is right I'll re-apply the protection and start tracking again.

The problem is that sometimes other libraries, for their own purposes, replace the `SIGSEGV` handler with their own, so bad things happen.

Recently I stumbled upon the `userfaultfd` mechanism which seems promising. As far as I understand it can basically detect two things (among others course):

a. Writes

b. Accesses to pages that haven't been allocated yet, but in this case you can tell if it's a read or a write.

So you can keep track of writes but for the reads you can only know if one happened on a page that was not allocated yet by the OS. Once it is allocated you can only keep track of writes.

Is my understanding correct?

So as far as I can tell this basically will not let me fulfill my 2nd requirement. I am trying to figure out ways to work around this but they are not going to be for free so I wanted to make sure that I am not missing something important.

Comment: Yep you're right, userfaultfd tracks *faults*, and a fault does not happen on a read on a present page.

Answer (score 2):

userfaultfd is not the right tool for your use case, if you want to track the accesses while a program is running you can use a sampling mechanism such as [PEBS](https://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html) and use the MEM_INST_RETIRED.ANY counter. Alternatively, you can use a tool like [PIN](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/98484/Pin/html/index.html) to instrument every memory access (load or store) of a running application. It would be useful if you mentioned what is the reason behind what you're doing, if you need to know accesses in real time to make memory management decisions, that's a lot more complicated than if you need an offline trace of accesses (which PIN provides).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to do this in real time. You are right I don't mention that. I am writing a Vulkan capture layer and I want to keep track of user access to device memory mapped to user space. Every frame I need to reset the protection and start tracking again.

Comment: One possible approach is to use eBPF (not sure if it's supported in your system) to track accessed bits periodically for reads